# Generate a table in R

Tags: r

I'm learning R and have this practice project.
I have a table like this (read from a csv file), but with a lot more lines:

```
    +----------+----------------+  
    | Home type| Gas consumption|    
    +----------+----------------+     
    |    1     |     31,2       |   
    |    2     |     51,3       |   
    |    3     |     40,4       |   
    |    3     |     100,0      |   
    |    2     |     34,6       |   
    |    1     |     16,0       |   
    +---+------------+----------+
```

I want to create an exhibit a table like this:

```
    +----------+----------+----------+----------+  
    | Measures |    1     |    2     |    3     |
    +-------------------------------------------+     
    |    Mean  |          |          |          |
    |    Medium|          |          |          |
    |    Min   |          |          |          |
    |    Max   |          |          |          |
    |    Q1    |          |          |          |
    |    Q3    |          |          |          |
    +----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

In other words, I'd like to sort my data into columns, where column1 represents the gas consumption of type 1 houses, column2 represents the gas consumption of type 2 houses and so on.
Then I want to compute the mean, medium, min, max, Q1 and Q3 of each column and display them as shown above.

Could you at least guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some dummy data:

```
d <- data.frame("Home Type"=c(1,2,3,3,2,1),
  "Gas Consumption"=c(31.2, 51.3, 40.4, 100.0, 34.6, 16.0))
```

Create a function that summarizes a vector with your requested metrics

```
stats <- function(x) c(Mean=mean(x), Median=median(x), Min=min(x), Max=max(x),
  Q1=quantile(x, 0.25), Q3=quantile(x, 0.75))
```

Split the variable of interest by Home Type and apply the function to each group

```
> data.frame(lapply(split(d$Gas.Consumption, d$Home.Type), stats), check.names = FALSE)

          1      2     3
Mean   23.6 42.950  70.2
Median 23.6 42.950  70.2
Min    16.0 34.600  40.4
Max    31.2 51.300 100.0
Q1.25% 19.8 38.775  55.3
Q3.75% 27.4 47.125  85.1
```